# unlocking iphone 5s on a different carrier

Tags: iphone, unlock

I own an iPhone 5s with iOS 8 (or above) locked to T-mobile carrier (USA), although I do not have the original sim. I am stuck on the setup page since I had reset the iPhone to factory setting and it keeps asking me for the original sim which i do not have. (IMEI checks does show that the iPhone is already activated as it was used on the original sim before) However, i put in a new sim from optus carrier (i am now in australia) and the network shows signal with 4G data, I have attached an image of it. Now my question is, is the iPhone sim locked? Can i just unlock the sim or would i have to unlock the iPhone? [image]

Answer (score 1):

afaik if the phone is network locked you'd need to be on the original carrier network to unlock it (then connect on itunes to complete etc) and whatever code is required (if any) must be applied with the original SIM.

Comment: I do not have the original sim. The network signal is showing on my phone with another carrier sim. Does it show if it is network locked?(Above picture)

Comment: i'm not sure :(
i once unlocked a samsung while it was abroad. it started working with another carrier SIM but would show the roaming symbol even if it was in the local network, with a local SIm. it only became 'normal' when it was reintroduced to the home network and after that it didnt show roaming when it used any local network with a local SIM. 

when i unlocked my iphone ages ago it was required to be in the original network.